# how to scroll whole content when bottom is fixed

Tags: css, responsive-design

So I have a bottom div which needs to be fixed in all screen size, and the remaining upper contents just get scrolled when the screen size gets sufficiently small.

```
.mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 70px;
  width: 100%;
}
.fixedBottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I've put `bottom: 70px` for the meantime to see lowers contents, when otherwise `0` the page wouldn't be able to scroll through the whole page as the bottom div is fixed hence hindering it. Well, this setup actually works on well on chrome, moz and opera but not on safari, my bottom div is whitened lol but the element is there.

Update: (temporary solution) since bottom div is fixed and it's going to be in the bottom of the page no matter what, put `fixedBottom` outside `mainContainer`. `mainContainer` becomes a sibling element to `fixedBottom` and wrap these elements into a div. However, I would still prefer `mainContainer` becoming a parent element.

Comment: Maybe give it `z-index: 1;`? Hard to tell without a working example

Comment: @Alon yea, tried that. put that under the mainContainer and the scroll does not work anymore. and the bottom still whitened. so it's not a layering problem.